# The code fails to generate the values I want, when both trigger pins 2, 3 are high or low. Why?

Tags: signal-processing

```cpp
/*aim of the program is to generate 2 different varying frequency from the
same output which is controlled by 2 triggers*/
void setup()
{
    pinMode(2,INPUT); //setting the trigger pins 2,3
    pinMode(3,INPUT);
    pinMode(6,OUTPUT); //output pin
}

void loop()
{
    if(digitalRead(2)==HIGH && digitalRead(3)==LOW) { //trigger conditions
        infra();
    }
    else if(digitalRead(2)==LOW && digitalRead(3)==HIGH) {
        red();
    }
    else if((digitalRead(2)==HIGH && digitalRead(3)==HIGH) || (digitalRead(2)==LOW && digitalRead(3)==LOW)) {
        Serial.println('help');
    }
}

void infra() //function varies sinosoidaly (working)
{
    float f;

    for(f=16000; f<=20525; f+=4.525) {
        tone(6,f);
    }

    for(f=20525; f>=16000; f=f-4.525) {
        tone(6,f);
    }
}

void red() //function varies sinosoidaly (working)
{
    float p;

    for(p=25000; p<=32071; p+=7.071) {
        tone(6,p);
    }

    for(p=32071; p>=25000; p=p-7.071) {
        tone(6,p);
    }
}
```

Comment: The third `if` is unnecesary.

Comment: 'Fails' means your code never print "help"?. You code never initialize Serial to start with ...

Comment: `'help'` is not a string.

Comment: `the code fails to generate the values i want` ... how does it fail?

Comment: @gre_gor I think you have found the problem. Would you care to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @per1234 OP's code doesn't print anything to serial because he is missing serial initialization. Printing `'help'` just prints some number.

Answer (score 2):

To send anything to serial you need to initialize it first with:

```cpp
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    //other code
}
```

And you are using wrong quotes for the string.
They should be double quotes `"` not single ones `'`.

Also you could simplify your code, if you removed the third `if`, since it's just checking the already known state at that point.

You should also read the button state only once, save them into a variable and then just compare those variables.

```cpp
bool button1_state = digitalRead(2);
bool button2_state = digitalRead(3);
if (button1_state && !button2_state) {
    infra();
}
else if (!button1_state && button2_state) {
    red();
}
else {
    Serial.println("help");
}
```